# python how to know the object attributes(methods) and how to know the hierarchy of the dict

Tags: python, object

I am working with the caffe Python wrapper. I have two questions about using Python to access the data details.

I first loaded the caffe net definition by:

```
net = caffe.Net('deploy_full.prototxt',caffe.TEST)
```

I know the net will be a object in Python, and I want to know the attributes within it, so I use the bulit-in dir() methods:

```
>>> dir(net)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__',         '__format__','__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__','__new__',    '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_backward', '_batch', '_blob_loss_weights', '_blob_names', '_blobs', '_forward', '_inputs', '_layer_names', '_outputs', '_set_input_arrays', 'backward', 'blob_loss_weights', 'blobs', 'copy_from', 'forward', 'forward_all', 'forward_backward_all', 'inputs', 'layers', 'outputs', 'params', 'reshape',     'save', 'set_input_arrays', 'share_with']
```

Then I used the params attribute to find the keys attribute of net.params:

```
>>> net.params.keys()
['conv1a', 'bn1a', 'conv1b', 'bn1b', 'conv2a', 'bn2a', 'conv2b', 'bn2b',  'conv3a', 'bn3a', 'conv3b', 'bn3b', 'fc8-conv']
```

So the problem is here, I want to know the detail about net.params['bn1a']:

```
>>> net.params['bn1a']
<caffe._caffe.BlobVec object at 0x7f274b71fbb0>
>>> dir(net.params['bn1a'])
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instance_size__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'add_blob', 'append', 'extend']
```

These outputs are not what I want, after googling somehow, I found want I want to see is achieved by these commands:

```
>>> net.params['bn1a'][0].data.shape
(1, 16, 1, 1)
>>> net.params['bn1a'][1].data.shape
(1, 16, 1, 1)
```

My problem is how could I know there should be [0], [1], and [x], in this dict? Since the net.params.keys() only told me there is key 'bn1a', but didn't tell me [num].

Moreover, if I didn't know there is [num] after ['bn1a'], I have no way to know the attributes of net.params['bn1a'][x], so I can't know the data and shape of these.

I would like to know what is the right way to peel the data/objects without knowledge beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in that case I would just go and check `BlobVec` class source code and find out `__iter__` method implementation and all other. But in your case it will not so helpful since `caffe._caffe.BlobVec` is actually points to [C++ implementation](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp#L241) when you can find that it's vector and fugure out about iterating over it etc if you know a thing about C++ and how it binds to Python and other awesome stuff :)

So in your case it's really better to check documentation. There under [Python section](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html) you'll find that

> Caffe blobs are exposed as numpy ndarrays for ease-of-use and efficiency.

Then you should just find docs about numpy arrays and you done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already checked those Caffe doc and CPP codes. It's helpful but of course time consuming. You help me make sure that I could not only know about my case from Python only. I think it's good for me to know how C++ binds to python myself, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Please accept the answer in order to make it helpful for future googlers.